# Zend custom form elements and decorators

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I started on developing custom form elements and decorators. I save them to the **zend/library/form** folder is that right?

And how do I use this custom elements?

```
$d = new My_Form_Element_Date('dateOfBirth');
$d->setLabel('Geburtsdatum:')
  ->setValue('20 April 2009');

$this->addElements(array($d));
```

Gives me the error that the location of the class could not be specified.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to register the namespace:

```
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance ()->registerNamespace('My_');
```

That's all!